# Apache beam - random numbers

Tags: apache-beam

What is the recommended way to generate random numbers with apache beam so that each entries is associated with the same random number if it retries processing the entry?

For example, to map each entries, I would like to treat 90% one way and 10% the other way. If a worker crashes and beam retries the processing, I need to ensure that the random number that dictates which way to process the entry stays the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality for that in Apache Beam. However you could write a DoFn that implements whatever random number generation you want for this use-case. For example, a DoFn that uses some unique identifier from each element (some kind of ID that would be unique but wouldn't change on retries) and runs it through a noise function to get a random value which it associates with that element.

Comment: You can call a hash function on the element - or if you update the elements, then the immutable parts of it. A suitable one is farm_fingerprint, which makes a 64 bit integer. To reduce it to a smaller range, take the remainder modulo the desired range size.